# Importing and analysing games played on chess.com

Tags: stockfish, online-chess

How to import entire game from chess.com game to stockfish?

Comment: This is really a question about features available on chess.com and as such it does not really fit into chess SE discussions. For such purposes, it's best to ask on the forum of the website itself, in this case: https://www.chess.com/forum

Answer (score 1):

I think chess.com has in-built Stockfish engine analysis, so I don't understand why you'd want to do that.

Don't like chess.com? lichess is easy. Just grab PGN of your game, [import it into lichess](https://lichess.org/paste). Select engine analysis.

Comment: Chess.com analysis is only useful for premium members. Other users have to suffer the non-in-depth analysis.

Comment: @WaisKamal What about lichess?

Comment: It is much better. Actually I also copy games from chess.com into lichess for analysis.

Comment: @SmallChess Lichess is both [free and open-source](https://lichess.org/about) ;) and what you've suggested is indeed perfectly feasible: in fact even as an anonymous user (guest), hover over "Tools" (tabs top of page) then choose "Analysis board" where you will be able to paste either FEN or PGN's to load up a game and then turn on the Stockfish engine (cloud).